# Jasper converting list of values of json to comma separated values using jsonQL

Tags: json, list, jasper-reports

we have json as list of values 
 "markets": [ { "id": "1001", "name": "val1" }, { "id": "1002", "name": "Val2" }, { "id": "1003", "name": "val3" } ]

using jasper report list component we want to display these list of values of name attribute comma separated in one text field.

with existing list the values of name are still coming as rows we want it to be 
single text field like this 
vale1,val2,val3

how can we use list of jasper report to loop through the values and show in single text fields as comma separated .

Thanks,
Anjana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a list for that, you could just use a variable like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3c4d8e3d-d3d5-4cb4-9b07-c67ce217d8dd">
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[..name]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="[0]"/>
    </field>
    <variable name="NameConcat" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{NameConcat} != null ? $V{NameConcat} + ", " + $F{name} : $F{name}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="180" y="10" width="200" height="30" uuid="fe01a39a-03e4-4a94-b9f7-3317caff6ae3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Concatenated values test]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#9AFBFC" uuid="59c0da96-00aa-4959-bdc4-4c9b9f7a2e2c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="748e4fce-3f0c-4df0-836a-45f9a92ac8b8"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <paragraph leftIndent="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Concatenated names]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <summary>
        <band height="30">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" uuid="2968b744-4b20-47cf-9fcb-05de58d606d0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <paragraph leftIndent="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NameConcat}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And the output:
[image: Report output]

Comment: Thanks Narcis. However the  reason i was thinking of list was because this list as part of parent structure we have to display name and market name as text field. 
"parent": {
 "name": "Test",
  "markets": [ { "id": "1001", "name": "val1" }, { "id": "1002", "name": "Val2" }, { "id": "1003", "name": "val3" } 
}

we might need a subdata set to reference markets with your solution of variable concatenation. 
not sure how to reference this subdata set in text field without list

Comment: You should have posted exactly what you want to achieve with complete data, not just fragments.

Comment: yes i understand i will try with your input . Thanks

Comment: This solves the issue however if there are more than one field using subdataset give list of values posed a query to subdataset for more one list of values .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068628/json-array-as-comma-separated-values-using-jsonql-in-jrxml